# ERROR: device '' not found. Skipping fsck and else

Tags: arch-linux, boot, btrfs, root-filesystem

```
:: running early hook [udev]
Starting systemd-udevd version 253.1-3-arch
:: running hook [udev]
:: Triggering uevents...
ERROR: device '' not found. Skipping fsck.
:: mounting '' on real root
mount: /new_root: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on , missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
sh: can't access tty; job xontrol turned off
```

Please help me how to fix that Arch Linux, nvme, btrfs. I tried to reinstall but still this error

Comment: Has it ever booted? If so what have you recently changed? If it hasn't, what make/model is the system? Please [edit] your question to add the detail as if you'd originally provided it. Don't comment here

Comment: Never i only installed it

Comment: ACPI errors have nothing to do with your issue. Either your kernel doesn't have the drivers for your storage or you specified the root fs incorrectly.

Comment: May be you know how to install arch without this errors

Comment: Since you're new to Linux, I'd recommend using a different more user-friendly distro such as Fedora or Ubuntu. Arch is for those who know Linux relatively well. It's like you wanted to start programming and instead of learning e.g. simple C, you dove straight into Assembler.

Comment: I just come trough internet and i liked idea of arch and performance may you know something like monjaro or fedora or you do not recommend them

Comment: Arch is *not* significantly faster than other Linux distros. Fedora has been my distro of choice for the past 25 years (starting with RedHat 5.0). If you need "fast", you use ClearLinux or Gentoo - they are both even less user-friendly. And when we are talking "faster" we are talking about 5-10% faster on average which you'll never be able to notice. You don't go for fast first, you go for user-friendly.

Comment: About performance i meant arch and Debian also arch has newer packages but im newbie

Comment: If you want newer packages try Mint or Ubuntu. Debian's strength is its stability - but at the expense of features